# Google Sheet / Custom Tab Salesforce

Tags: tab, google-apps

Recently seen something on SF where they had a tab and when clicked on would open a google sheet inside Salesforce. Any ideas how to implement this?

Hoping to hear from anyone. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you are talking about [Apex Connector for Lightning Connect: Make Anything a Salesforce Object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7Tfru19nS0) video from dreamforce

you need to turn on [Lightning Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229286&language=en_US&type=1) by contacting account executive

> This is currently a paid feature. Please contact your account
>   executive to have the feature added to your organization